# TestFixtureSetup and TestFixtureTearDown do not run for each TestCase

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I have several TestCase's within a single TestFixture. I also have a single TestFixtureSetup method (Setup()) and TestFixtureTearDown method (TearDown()). When running all of the tests, however, SetUp() and TearDown() are only run once, rather than each time a TestCase is executed. Is this the expected behavior? If it is, is there a way to make the methods run each time a TestCase runs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods adorned with `[TestFixtureSetUp]` and `[TestFixtureTearDown]` are run once for all tests.
Methods adorned with `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` are run before and after each test case, so you want to use these.

Here is a sample order of execution, including constructor and a `Dispose` method. Method names correspond with attributes that decorate them:

`NUnitTestClass..ctor
NUnitTestClass.TestFixtureSetUp
NUnitTestClass.SetUp
NUnitTestClass.TestMethod1
NUnitTestClass.TearDown
NUnitTestClass.SetUp
NUnitTestClass.TestMethod2
NUnitTestClass.TearDown
NUnitTestClass.TestFixtureTearDown
NUnitTestClass.Dispose`

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is the expected behavior. Per the Nunit documentation:

> [TestFixtureTearDownAttribute] is used inside a TestFixture to provide a single set of functions that are performed once after all tests are completed.

If you want something to run for every test I'd suggest creating a class which implements IDisposable. Assume it's called TestSpan or something. Then you can do:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests()
{

    [TestCase]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var span = new TestSpan()
        using(span)
        {
            // Do test stuff
        }
    }
}

public class TestSpan: IDisposable
{
    TestSpan()
    {
        // Do Test Setup Stuff
    }

    Dispose()
    {
        // Do Test Cleanup Stuff
    }
}
```